# How to insert a header on SharePoint page

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I have a very simple requirement but of course as is the case with CSOM it seems really difficult to achieve anything. I did have a solution for this, but now that the site template has changed (outside of my control) nothing works any more, and I have no idea how to debug this.

**Requirement**

Add a simple header to an existing SharePoint page.

**Old solution**

This used to work great. I pass in the page name, the web part xml and the details of the zone (I have no idea how I found those it seems ridiculously complicated just to insert a web part with code... why?...)

When i try it now I get

> the object specified does not belong to a list

On the 2nd `ExecuteQuery()`

```
private void InsertWebPart(ClientContext clientContext, string webPartXml, string markerTemplate, 
    string pagePath, string zoneId, int zoneIndex, string description, string content, string fieldName)
{
    var relUrl = new Uri(baseUrl).AbsolutePath;

    clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
    var web = clientContext.Web;

    var page = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($"{relUrl}/{pagePath}");
    var webPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

    var importedWebPart = webPartManager.ImportWebPart(webPartXml);
    var webPart = webPartManager.AddWebPart(importedWebPart.WebPart, zoneId, zoneIndex);
    clientContext.Load(webPart);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var marker = string.Format(markerTemplate, webPart.Id);

    var item = page.ListItemAllFields;
    clientContext.Load(item);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    item[fieldName] = marker + item[fieldName];
    item.Update();

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I tried [this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223803/how-could-i-change-the-sharepoint-page-title) but all I get is

> the object specified does not belong to a list

Again... Please can someone advise?

How hard can it be to just simply add 1 header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the solution below:

1.You can add "?contents=1" in the current site page, and remove the custom web part which add it using the CSOM code.

2.Open the site page using SharePoint designer, and edit in Advanced Mode.

3.Add the Header HTML code and JavaScript code under the "PlaceHolderMain" control.

Example code:

```
<div id="customHeader" style="height:20px;width:auto;background-color:green">Test</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#ms-designer-ribbon").before($("#customHeader"));
});
</script>
```

4.Save the page.

[image]

If you can't use the SharePoint designer, we can also use script editor web part/content editor web part with some HTML code to achieve it.

If you want to make all the page have the custom header, we can add some code into the master page to make it works.